# Does the rotation of a frisbee have any noticeable effect on the frisbee lift?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics, lift

If you throw a frisbee horizontally (with zero attack angle), the only uplifting force comes from the rim, which makes the air above the frisbee move faster and thus (Bernoulli) decreases the pressure above the frisbee.

But what if you manage to give the frisbee very much spin. How does this spin affect the velocities of the air (and thus the pressures) on both sides of the frisbee? My guess is that a higher spin gives the frisbee an extra uplifting force (and thus not only stabilises the frisbee).

Comment: Why do you think higher spin provides extra lifting force? What is the physics behind your thinking?

Comment: I've googled a lot, but I only found the uplifting force due to the forward motion. I guess the rotation doesn't contribute a lot because frisbees are very smooth and if the rotation would affect the velocity of the surrounding air too much, the rotation of the frisbee would decrease too much, which would destabilise the frisbee too quick.

Comment: @sammygerbil-I think the rotation of the frisbee would affect the velocity of the air above the frisbee more than the air under the frisbee (because of the rim), which would create a nett upward force (Bernoulli again). The air under the top of the frisbee is sucked downwards (the moving air beneath the frisbee creates a lower pressure), so the air "inside" the frisbee has a lower density. Because of this lower density, the rotation of the frisbee will affect more air above the surface more than right under the surface.

Comment: Perhaps a better title would be to ask about the effect of rotation speed on **lift** rather than on the **air pressure** surrounding the disc, because it seems not altogether clear how air pressure affects lift eg via the Bernoulli Principle.

Comment: No, at least to first order (neglecting the effect that spin has on the stability of the boundary layer forming over the Frisbee) the spin will not affect the lift.

Comment: The effect of increasing spin is something which you could very easily investigate for yourself. Have you done any testing of your idea?

Comment: @Pirx-Why are you so sure of the outcome of the experiment? See for example the effect of rotation given in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard it claimed that the bent shape of the frisbee traps air below it and tends to make that air corotate with the frisbee.  This supposedly increases lift, by increasing the contrast between the airspeed above and below the disk of a rapidly spinning disk, as opposed to one with less spin that doesn't trap air as well.  However, I don't believe this is correct, because if air corotates with the disk, the motion of the air comes from viscosity, not from pressure gradients.  So the impact on pressure would be incorrect in the Bernoulli approximation.  Hence, in my opinion, there is no effect on lift that comes from spin-- there's only the stabilizing of the angle of attack.  But to be honest, it's a pretty difficult question to answer theoretically, that's why there are wind tunnels! Also, the use of the Bernoulli effect in aerodynamics has a checkered history, to say the least.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52735/discussion-on-answer-by-ken-g-does-the-rotation-of-a-frisbee-have-any-noticeable).

Comment: @KenG-Why doesn't the change in velocity caused by viscosity count in reducing the upward pressure?

Comment: If one is using the Bernoulli theorem, there is no viscosity.  Also, the guts of the Bernoulli theorem (without gravity, which is playing no role here)  is that if you split two flows, and one of them speeds up, it has to be because of a pressure gradient-- not because of dragging against a frisbee.  Of course, if one is not using the Bernoulli thinking, one has a much more complicated problem.